# LRU Clock Replace Algorithm - What are reference bits initialized to?

Tags: cpu-architecture, lru, tlb

Suppose I have a 2 entry TLB and am using LRU Clock replacement. Further suppose that I have a TLB miss and its a page fault, so I load in a page into memory and update TLB, now my TLB has 1 entry. Next, I have another TLB miss and its a page fault, so I load in a page into memory and update TLB now my TLB is full.

Now, let us say that there is an another TLB miss and its a page fault and I need to evict an entry from my TLB using LRU Clock.

My question is, is the reference bit for the two entries in the TLB 1? (i.e. When we add in a new TLB entry do we set the reference bit to 1 initially? Or is it initialized to 0?). If not is the first TLB entry's reference bit 0 and the second a 1? (Would this be because during the 2nd-page fault we set the reference bit for the first entry to 0?)

Lastly which entry would be evicted? (first or second)

Comment: For a 2-way LRU TLB, you only one reference bit per pair of TLB entries. The ref bit can be interpreted in multiple ways. For example, if that bit is set to zero, it means that the first entry is the LRU, and if it's one, it means that the second entry is the LRU. Whichever entry is currently marked as the LRU is the once to be evicted. Note that there are variants of LRU.